# android sorry application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator

The following code works fine without any errors but when i try to get the url through intent i get the error the application stopped unexpectedly. can anyone please help me out.

```
public class MjpegSample extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String URL = "http://121.6.98.160:8081/videostream.cgi?"
                   + "user=admin&pwd=admin&resolution=8"; 
    }
}
```

The following code make the error when i replace the above code:

```
public class MjpegSample extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String URL;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        URL = extras.getString("flink");
    }
}
```

To get the "flink" by intent i use the following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewcam);
    t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    p=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    i=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip);
    po=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String tt=t.getText().toString();
            String pp=p.getText().toString();
            String ii=i.getText().toString();
            String por=po.getText().toString();
            String link="http://"+ii+":"+por
                       +"/videostream.cgi?user="+tt
                       +"&pwd="+pp+"resolution=8";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MjpegSample.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("flink",link);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);                

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the value of "URL = extras.getString("flink");"

Comment: paste your logcat here..

Comment: why are you using startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); to start activity? I think that causes the problem. Is this code written inside a single activity? or in different activity? Tell me that. I can help you

Comment: value of "URL = extras.getString("flink"); is the url that has been got from another class by intent.

Comment: the code is written inside a single acitvity only. bt i used intent to pass the string flink from one activity to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `v.getContext()` with `NameOfCurrentActivity.this`,
Also check in the other Activity:

```
if (extras != null)
{
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: i have tried it doesnt solve my problem... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You should get the url directly from the intent, not from the extras:

```
getIntent().getString("flink")
```